# Prove there are infinitely many gaussian primes on a given line

Tags: number-theory

For a given $a \in \mathbb{Z}$，how to prove there are infinite gaussian primes with the form of $a+b i$ ?

Comment: When $b=1$ this is equivalent to asking about infinitude of primes of the form $a^2 + 1$, and that is a well-known open problem. Gaussian primes are known to be equidistributed in angular sectors (Hecke’s theorem), but in a vertical or horizontal strip in the first quadrant the existence of infinitely many Gaussian primes  is unsolved in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

[It is conjectured but unproven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) (unless $a=0$).

If $ab\ne 0$ then
$a+ib$ is a Gaussian prime iff $a^2+b^2$ is an integer prime.

Comment: Thanks. Then how about another weaker statement: For any positive even number, it can be expressed as a sum of two gaussian primes. Is it also unproven?

Comment: @user32688 that seems completely unrelated; maybe ask another question?

Comment: How about this. Change the `infinity` to `at least one`. Given $a$, show there is at least one gaussian prime with the form of $a+bi$